# get param value after rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress

I defined the custom rewrite rule to add parameters.

```
([a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{3})/?$ -> index.php?sponsor=$matches[1]
```

I defined the new parameter with this code:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($args) {
    return array_merge($args, array('sponsor'));
});

add_action('init', function() {
    global $wp_query;
    print_r($wp_query->query_vars);
});
```

Obviously I would not be here if this worked! The print_r prints an empty array.

Ideas?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

```
add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('sponsor', EP_ALL);
});

add_filter('request', function($args) {
    print_r($args);

    return $args;
});
```